# Applying image texture to UV Map

Tags: texturing, image

I know how to apply an image texture to a UV map, but the result is unpredictable and often looks terrible.

Let's say I have a texture I want to apply:

[image: collage of blue stripe textures]

...and lets say that, since it looks like a sphere already, I'd like to apply it to a sphere.  But not just any sphere...a sphere with a extrusion or two.

My UV Map clearly isn't a circle.  Even on a perfect sphere getting the image to look like the picture seems impossible.  Or the cube for that matter, given that the texture image shows no seams at all.

So how is this done?

Is it a lot harder to use an image like that that is already prepared than it is to simply paint your own UV maps?  Or is there some simple way of extracting parts of this image to be used in a UV map?

If anyone can point me to any youtube tutorials on this it would be amazing, thank you.  I can't find any.

Cheers,

A

below, example UV map of what I'm working with:

[image]

Comment: This is pretty broad, do you have a concrete example with a picture of the UV map that you are having trouble with?

Comment: I've added a UV image to the post as an example, as I can't put an image in comments.

Comment: Ouch, thats a messy UV map. You might want to have a go at marking seams and trying a more specific unwrap.

Comment: The shape is complex.  The UV map is always going to be a bit like this, but even if it were simpler please can you answer my original question?